# Why no tag for tags on mechanical constructions?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags

I personally have written quite a few questions concerning mechanical mechanisms. My trouble is I believe [engineering](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engineering) to be too broad and [mechanics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanics) being ambiguous.

Is there anything I can do in this situation to make the tagging more precise, or should I leave it as-is?

Comment: What do you mean by mechanical mechanisms? From a glance, it seems that those tags would fit. Linking to some examples would also help to explain why the tags don’t suit your needs. (Also, magic links don’t work in questions and answers, only comments. You’ll need to directly link to the tag page if you want to reference them)

Comment: @LiamMorris As in cogwheels, springs and pulleys. It works, but engineering can be anything from civil to electronic engineering. Mechanics can just be systems in a world such as the mechanics of flower pollination.

Comment: New tags can be created if there are gaps.  What would you name it and what would you give as a short description (tag wiki)?  If you edit that info into your question it'll be easier for us to understand what you're looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

My vote is for [machines](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machines), which would not be specific to a type or expression of machines.

If specification beyond that is required, then we'd want tags (as needed) like [mechanical](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanical), [electricity](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electricity) (already exists), [optic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optic) (already exists), etc.

I'm a little surprised we don't already have a [machines](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machines) tag.  Granted, people on this site tend to ask 99% of the time about [weapons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons).  It's kindof a relief to get questions about other kinds of machines.

Comment: Not enough for an answer, as I think "machines" would be a reasonable addition.  That said, I don't see what's wrong with "engineering".  Machines and mechanical devices and tools have been the stock in trade of the engineer since ancient times.

Comment: @elemtilas [tag:engineering] can be used for bridges and roads.  Personally, I can see a difference between the process of engineering and the results of engineering.  Hence, [tag:engineering] and [tag:machines].  Considering the level of disinterest this meta question is getting, Lambent probably needs to simply make a choice and roll forward.

Comment: Like I said, I'm not adverse to the creation of "machines" as a tag; though I am not convinced that "engineering" is inappropriate.  Agreed: piss or get off the pot.